# What does QL mean in experimental condensed matter physics (thin film growth)?

Tags: condensed-matter, experimental-physics, crystals, topological-insulators

In literatures of thin film growth I often see the unit QL. It often occurs at contexts like "a 64 QL film," "the growth occurs QL-by-QL," and "the growth rate was found to be 1 QL/min." I suspect L means layer, but I am not sure what Q means.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the system it could be "Quadruple Layer" or "Quintuple Layer", for units consisting of four or five layers, respectively. Typically the abbreviation should be defined somewhere in the paper, so e.g. Ctrl+F can be quite useful.